# Django Wagtail Pages -1

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I flushed my database to reset my website in my Django Wagtail project and now I cannot add any page to my Wagtail website.
Here you can find the screenshot. There is no option to add pages. Any solutions? Or do I have to create a new project and reset everything?

[image: pages shows -1 and there is no option to add the page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create a whole new project, but I'd suggest deleting and recreating the database - the initial migrations to set up the Wagtail database tables include a few essential records (such as a root node for the page tree), and these will have been deleted when you flushed the database.

If you're running sqlite (the default for a new project), there'll be a file in the project root named `db.sqlite3`, or with a name of the form `[name-of-project].db` - delete this file, then re-run `./manage.py migrate`.

If you're using PostgreSQL, run `dropdb name-of-project` then `createdb name-of-project` (you might also need an option like `-U postgres` depending on how your permissions are set up), then `./manage.py migrate`.